# What are the Ānāpānasati Kammaṭṭhāna as Taught By Ven. Kiribathgoda Gnanananda Thero

Tags: personal-practice, teaching, meditation-breath, anapanasati

I am curious to know how Ven. Kiribathgoda Gnanananda Thero teachers Ānāpānasati. Does he follow the 16 stage instructions or perhaps something similar to the 8 step method<sup>1</sup> or combination of both or something different with or without overlap.

<sup>NB: In answering this please make this a self contained answer without having to navigate links and audio files.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
[Anapana Sati Meditation on Breathing](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyadhamma/bl115.html) by Ven. Mahathera Nauyane Ariyadhamma

Comment: Is it possible to elect an answer now? Anything specific you were looking for in the answers?

Comment: I am looking for more step by step guide with proper online citations.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://mahamevnawa.lk/meditation/

Comment: Answer to this would be a summary of that is in these talks.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly it is concentrating on one's breath as **"l'm inhaling short, I'm exhaling short" or otherwise "I'm inhaling long, I'm exhaling short**".

This is what Lord Buddha asks us to do in the beginning. He also says this meditation isn't for everybody. This meditation isn't the only way to understand the Four Noble Truths.

Official Website: http://mahamevnawa.lk/

Meditation Section: 
http://mahamevnawa.lk/meditation/

You can find English sessions of Sound Cloud in that website and might find English guides on meditation.

The thero also published a book in sinhalese called **É Ama Nivan Suwa Bohoo Dura Nowe** (ඒ අමා නිවන් සුව බොහෝ දුර නොවේ - The Nirvana is not that far away) which explains Maha Satipattana Sutta, which contains the above form of breathing. Buddha states also to note that the breath isn't me, mine or my soul (hence the book contains it).

Answer (score -2):

The mundane way to do the Anapanasati Meditation is given in the interpretations 
 that are out there of the following Doctrinal Discourses -  Ananda Sutta (Leading to Awakening) SAMYUTTA NIKAYA 12:10; Girimananda Sutta (To Girimananda) ANGUTTARA NIKAYA 10.60; Anapanasati Sutta (Mindfulness of Breathing)  MAJJIMA NIKAYA 118 Etc. Etc.  The Supreme Buddha explained to Venerable Ananda (Among the greatest 10 disciples of the Buddha, the one who had the most retentive memory), “This one factor is Anapanasati, which when developed and pursued brings the Four Foundations of Mindfulness (Cattaro Satipatthana) to completion. The Four Foundations of Mindfulness, when developed and pursued bring the Seven Factors of Enlightenment to completion. The Seven Factors of Enlightenment, when developed and pursued bring Clear Knowing and Release to completion.”
The million dollar question is whether any of these interpretations of the Anapanasati Meditation is correct or not.

Answer (score -4):

I'm glad you asked Suminda here are some of Mahamewnawa teachings on Vipassana...

This is the only one i could find on Anapanasathi Meditation

[Liberation through Breath (Meditation of Breathing)](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/75_Anapanasathi_Bhavana.mp3)

---

Our monastery concentrate more on the vipassana Meditation. Here are some of the popular ones.......

[Just a body with movement (Meditation of posturest full awarness)](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/76_Meditation_of_Posturest_full_Awareness.mp3)

[A bag with an opening at both ends (Meditation of foulness)](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/77_Meditation_of_Foulness.mp3)

[Slaughtered cow (Meditation on elements)](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/78_Meditation_on_Elements.mp3)

[Verily my own body, too (Meditation on nine cemetery contemplations)](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/79_Meditation_on_Nine_Cemetery_Contemplations.mp3)

[Asubha – Anapanasathi Meditation](http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/49_Asuba_Aanaapaana_sathi.mp3)

Comment: The OP wanted an answer, and not a link to an audio file -- see also [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as “not an answer”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95691/139866), and, [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/139866) -- can you answer, possibly answer by summarizing what's in the audio file (if the audio file does contain an answer to the question)? Or is the answer that the monastery *doesn't* teach Anapanasati?

Comment: Does the questioner seeks for an answer or seeks for nurishment of his field? Its good to see "there are gifts and sacrifies" rather to demand, isn't it Nyom @ChrisW ? Not to speak that the OP-operator started him self with less effort to explain his question in providing a link. So how about Question containing links? To risky to limit in this sphere and failing to get enough food?

Comment: @SamanaJohann The purpose of this site is to get and give answers to questions (see the policy described at e.g. "[Answers vs Advice](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61/answers-vs-advice)"). So if an answer doesn't answer whatever the question is, I comment to try to encourage the user to answer the question. The OP said "without links to audio files" and Theravada posted links to audio files, so it doesn't answer the question. The OP (Suminda) probably already tried to answer his own question by reviewing the Mahamevnawa web site and already found nothing but audio files.

Comment: More and more Nyom @ChrisW appears like a brain washed slave of this page, not a little able to read listen an reflect. Is he aware of this I-am-a-bot-mind ? Then, if not found, he would be great in giving like he likes to receive and not play another SE-slave and force growd-work for other mans business, wouldn't he?

Comment: Ven. Ariyadhamma [left his last life](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2419.msg10535.html#msg10535) already meanwhile, some about not a year ago, so one more less to pay respect and ask proper.

Comment: The fist answer is neither down voted nor rebuked at the same time, just to make dust more visible.

Comment: @SamanaJohann A purpose of comments are to suggest improvements to the answer.

Comment: @SamanaJohann When you address comments like "@ChrisW appears like a brain washed slave" or similar, what kind of reply or reaction do you hope to read in reply?

Comment: None, just that @ChrisW might make use of such for his welfare. But it's up to him whether he takes it to refelect or to just react, programmed like. Atma trusts that he is actually wise enought.